# Tabulate Area using GDAL and Numpy

Tags: gdal, numpy, zonal-statistics, tabulate

How could I perform a `Tabulate Area` using GDAL and Numpy?  I am trying to summarize how many pixels of each class in a Landcover raster are within each polygon of a Census Blocks shapefile.

I've tried playing with `numpy.histogram2d`, but didn't have any luck.

Comment: Have a look at the code of my QGIS plugin LecoS (or use it directly). It can extract raster values per polygon using scipy and PIL.

Answer (score 2):

try something like this:

```
import gdal
import numpy as np

area_per_pixel = 100 #example...you change to suit

r = gdal.Open(rasterfile)
band = 1
raster_arr = np.array(r.GetRasterBand(band).ReadAsArray())

for cover in np.unique(raster_arr):
    tot_num_pixels = np.sum(raster_arr == cover)
    area = tot_num_pixels * area_per_pixel
    print cover, area
```

as for you shapefile and exactly what's going on there, I'm not sure since we cannot see it.